# Display Specific Median Value in Boxplot

Tags: matlab

I want the following boxplot:
[image: The Boxplot]

to have the specific median value on the red line.

Is that possible?

Comment: Calculate the `median` and use `text` to place the values. TLDR; yes it's possible. Show a [mcve] for us to help, or this question is too broad to be on topic.

Answer (score 1):

```
text(1, mean1+1,mean1);
text(2, mean2+1,mean2);
text(3, mean3+1,mean3);
text(4, mean4+1,mean4);
```

if you change the `+1` to another number it elevates the text by that amount.